# Efficient way to structure a followers timeline in a noSQL setting

Tags: firebase, data-structures, timeline, nosql

Lets say I have users who can follow each other. They can also post items, lets call them tweets.

Now, like on Twitter, when a user posts a tweet it should be shown on the timeline (ordered) of all followers of this user.

In a noSQL setting, how would one structure the nodes such that the timelines for each user is loaded quick and efficiently?

To give you a **non-efficient example**:

```
tweets
      /$tweetId
           /userId
           /date

followers
      /$userId
            /$followerId
```

To retrieve the timeline of user1, one would retrieve 1) the complete list of follower ids, 2) filter out all tweets for each followerId, 3) sort it. Obviously this would take ages when the network grows.

What are some better ways to structure this problem?

Optional question: are there some known solutions or databases that handle these problems?

Comment: This is an incredibly broad topic. But in general you should *fan out* the data, so that the tweets that a user sees are in a single user-specific location, i.e. their wall. For an example of this, see this Firebase example: https://firefeed.io/

Comment: A good overview of NoSQL data modeling: https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/

Comment: Thanks for that, seems like a good starter. What I am worried about with copying the spark ids to multiple nodes, is that when one write fails, the previous ones should be undone as well. But I think that should be a separate question. Does Firebase have something that can handle those write/delete operations. I.e., could I write and somehow connect all sparks simultaneously on several nodes?

Comment: Uhh wait, I think I found something: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-07-how-to-keep-your-data-consistent.html

Comment: Yup. Multi-location updates are a solution for that. We didn't get around to updating firefeed for it yet. But be certain to not take your "it's atomic" too far: if someone has a million followers any form of multi-location update (or worse: transaction) is going to seriously hurt concurrency on your application.

Comment: Makes sense. Do you have any insights on how Twitter does it? Is it a matter of data structure or just some serious servers doing the heavy lifting?

Comment: Last time I read about it, Twitter fanned out the data similar to how Firefeed does it. Serious servers help, but it's also a matter of not thinking in terms of transactions. You want the tweet to show up for all followers *eventually* (preferably relatively soon). But it doesn't have to be at the exact same time.

Comment: I hope this is not too much off topic, but is this also the way to go to keep track of the statistics for a certain tweet? I.e. the data should be structured in a simolar fashion and updated through the multi-patg setting? Perhals there is a way to easily increment it. I just feel that ot gets complicated when tags change or are added.